# Instantiating a function

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

This question is about a different instance that im trying to instantiate...
I have to get the "Read" function from my Cardreader class and return a string to it on the form1.vb .... Now i did what i can remeber but for some reason i'm having a problem with the brackets.... What can i do to fix this?

Form1.vb

```
ThisATM.getCardReader.Readr("TEST TEXT IS FUN")
```

CardReader.vb

```
Public Function Readr(ByVal card As KeyCard) As String
        Return Read
    End Function
```

[Link for the image of the card reader function. I thought this link of the image of the code would be easier to understand.](http://i41.tinypic.com/33l1g1v.jpg)

Comment: I tryed using intellsense's idea which was automatically put some random code in `   Sub Readr(ByVal p1 As String)
        Throw New NotImplementedException
    End Sub
` i dont think it was right

Comment: Just tried making `read` as a string and putting `card as keycard` somewhere else... didnt work i think i made it worse....

Answer (score 1):

The Readr function takes an KeyCard as parameter, not an string. So it seems like you have to create an instance to an KeyCard and use that as a parameter instead. In the code in the image you provided you are creating a keycard object, it seems like you should use that object in the Readr function like this:

```
Dim ThisKeyCard as new KeyCard("1234","5678","Mikki Monster")
Dim returnString as string=ThisATM.getCardReader.Readr(ThisKeyCard)
```